# DVD is not detected

Tags: bios, dvd, compact-disc, desktop-computer

My system is not detecting DVDs but it's detecting CDs just fine.

- I have completely formatted the system but the problem still occurs
- I have a LG **HL-DT-ST DVD-RAM GSA-H55N** model drive.

Comment: Read this, it might help - http://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/99286-hl-dt-st-dvd-ram-gsa-h55n-ata-device-wont-read-dvds-but-reads-cd-2.html

Comment: I have Clean Install of XP.. 
Intel BIOS is updated to latest.. Tried rollback also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is independent of OS (i.e. booting from DVD also does not work) and you have tried some known good DVDs you drive is likely broken.

Why is it still capable of reading CDs? Reading DVDs and CDs require different wavelengths so it could be as simple as a worn out laser for the DVD wavelength (650 nm). DVDs also have higher requirements on the optics due to smaller structure so dust or some misalignment could also be a problem.

Comment: It didn' work i have got a drive from my frnd which works fine.. so the problem is on drive.. not on system. so i tried to clean the lens with buds but it doesn't work well.. anyway thanks for the help..!

Comment: @special did you try the same drive (model), or a different one? I don't think it was the drive.

Comment: @ekaj Changing anything in Windows will not help if the problem also exists on another OS or when trying to boot from DVD. So what do you think is the problem, if it is not the drive itself? Wrong cabling would also affect CDs.

Comment: It wasn't tested on another OS, so wew ouldn't know. Also, others with the same drive have had the same problem.

Comment: @ekaj The described problem with lower and/or upper filters is not specific to this model, it can happen with any drive. And if I understand special correctly, booting from DVD in the drive *was* tested.

Comment: @ekaj: Same Model .. I am unable to even boot the dvd.. but cd work fine..

Comment: @GurkenPapst: Boot from DVD also failed.. it doesn't even detected it..!